# Extract date from tweets (Tweepy, Python)

Tags: python, date, twitter, data-science, tweepy

I'm new to Python, and so I'm struggling a bit with this. Basically, the code below gets the text of tweets with the hashtag bitcoin in it, and I want to extract the date and author as well as the text. I've tried different things, but stuck rn.
Greatly appreciate any help with this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tweepy

api_key = '*'
api_secret_key = '*'
access_token = '*'
access_token_secret = '*'

authentication = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret_key)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(authentication, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

#Get tweets about Bitcoin and filter out any retweets
search_term = '#bitcoin -filter:retweets'
tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, q=search_term, lang='en', since='2018-11-01', tweet_mode='extended').items(50)
all_tweets = [tweet.full_text for tweet in tweets]


df = pd.DataFrame(all_tweets, columns=['Tweets'])
df.head()
```

Comment: what is your problem? Do you get error or what? if you get error then show it in question (not in comments) as text. If you get wrong data then show it also in question. Don't expect that we will run code to see problem. And code may work correctly on out computers.

Comment: Problem is that I'm stuck, I've tried different things but from the code above I've only been able to get the text of the tweets, not the date.

Comment: you can use `dir(tweet)` to see all variables in functions in object `tweet`. It may help tp see what you can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `dir(tweet)` then you see all variables and functions in object `tweet`

```
author
contributors
coordinates
created_at
destroy
display_text_range
entities
extended_entities
favorite
favorite_count
favorited
full_text
geo
id
id_str
in_reply_to_screen_name
in_reply_to_status_id
in_reply_to_status_id_str
in_reply_to_user_id
in_reply_to_user_id_str
is_quote_status
lang
metadata
parse
parse_list
place
possibly_sensitive
retweet
retweet_count
retweeted
retweets
source
source_url
truncated
user
```

And there is `created_at`

```
all_tweets = []

for tweet in tweets:
    #print('\n'.join(dir(tweet)))
    all_tweets.append( [tweet.full_text, tweet.created_at] )

df = pd.DataFrame(all_tweets, columns=['Tweets', 'Created At'])
df.head()
```

Result:

```
                                           Tweets                Created At
0  @Ralvero Of course $KAWA ready for 100x #ETH ... 2022-03-26 13:51:06+00:00
1  Pairs:1INCHUSDT \n SELL:1.58500\n Time :3/26/2...  2022-03-26 13:51:06+00:00
2  @hotcrosscom @iSafePal  First LIVE Dapp: Cylu... 2022-03-26 13:51:04+00:00
3  @Justdoitalex @Isabel_Schnabel Finally a truth...  2022-03-26 13:51:03+00:00
4  #Bitcoin has rejected for the fourth time the ...  2022-03-26 13:50:55+00:00
```

---

But your code have problem with `since` because it seems it was removed in version 3.8

See: [Collect tweets in a specific time period in Tweepy, until and since doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64198102/collect-tweets-in-a-specific-time-period-in-tweepy-until-and-since-doesnt-work)